# Material Design 3 Top app bar does not have a shadow. How to enable it?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, material-you

The new 'Material Design 3 top app bar' docs says they got rid of the drop shadow.
How can I enable it? Setting elevation on Toolbar or AppBar does not work at all.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same situation. I found that:

1. The shadow drop applies starting from API 28, below API 28 - the shadow effect is the same as with a MaterialComponents theme.
2. A color fill works below API 28 (tested on API 26).

Docs for [Top app bar specs](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs) says that the **container** of the TopAppBar has a role **"Surface"** and **Elevation (on scroll)** ***Level 2***.

On the page [Color system - Color roles](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles) I found information that:

> At elevation +2 components with surface color containers receive a primary color overlay with 8% opacity.

So the default style for a TopAppBarLayout uses *?attr/colorSurface* as a background color and *?attr/colorPrimary* with 8% opacity as an **overlay** (kind of a scrim effect).

**My solution:**

- **Case 1** - Only enable a shadow effect.

Create a style for AppBarLayout and set **android:outlineAmbientShadowColor** and **android:outlineSpotShadowColor** to black (as it's a default color for creating shadow). These attributes are set as transparent in *Widget.Material3.AppBarLayout*.

```
<style name="Widget.App.AppBarLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.AppBarLayout">
      <item name="android:outlineAmbientShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
      <item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

- **Case 2** - Enable a shadow effect and get rid of the overlay.

In addition to the above you can add either an *android:background* attribute with you color or a *materialThemeOverlay* attribute with setting colorSurface to your color (a background) and colorPrimary to @android:transparent (an overlay). I prefer to add directly *android:background* because adding *materialThemeOverlay* can have impact on the child views of your AppBarLayout which.

```
   <style name="Widget.App.AppBarLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.AppBarLayout">
        <item name="android:outlineAmbientShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

or

```
<style name="Widget.App.AppBarLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.AppBarLayout">
        <item name="android:outlineAmbientShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor" ns1:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.DayNight.NoActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Don't forget apply your style to your AppBarLayout or theme.

By the way, a *liftOnScroll* attribute is set to true in **Widget.Material3.AppBarLayout** so there's no need for setting it. Everything works with setting only *layout_behavior* for a scrolling view.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answers above only tackle Android but i'm not seeing the shadow on iOS, but i suppose the following should work also for Android

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 6,
    shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
    ...
  )
  ...
)
```

or globally to apply on all pages

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.red,
      background: Colors.grey.shade50,
    ),
    useMaterial3: true,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      elevation: 6,
      shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
    ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, special attribute for your theme from [material docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#using-surface-colors)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update code with surfaceTinColor and shadowColor.

```
AppBar(
   backgroundColour: blue, //whatever you want
   surfaceTinColor: blue, // backgraound of appbar when you scroll
   elevetion: 4, // default level of material 2
   shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6), //looks good to me
)
```